# Find the range of $P= \frac{\sum_{1}^n x_i}{\prod _{1}^n (x_i^2+1)}$

Tags: calculus, inequality

When I solved the following problem.

Find the range of $B\equiv\dfrac{x+y}{(x^2+1)(y^2+1)}$ where $x,y \in\mathbb{R}$.

Solution.
Setting $x=\tan u$ and $y=\tan v$, expression is $\frac{\sin 2u+\sin 2v+\sin (2u+2v)}4$

And from there, it is not very complex to get upperbound when $u=v=\frac{\pi}6$ and opposite lowerbound.

Hence the result : $\boxed{\text{Range is }\left[-\frac{3\sqrt 3}8,\frac{3\sqrt 3}8\right]}$

But I don't how to solve the generalization problem: 
Find the range of $P=\displaystyle \dfrac{\sum_{1}^n x_i}{\prod _{1}^n (x_i^2+1)}$ where $x_i \in\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 4):

Notice that:

1. $P$ is continuous on $\mathbb R^n$.
2. $P(x_1, \dotsc, x_n) \ge 0$ for any $x_1, \dotsc, x_n \ge 0$.
3. $P(0, \dotsc, 0) = 0$.
4. $P(x_1, \dotsc, x_n) \to 0$ as $(x_1, \dotsc, x_n) \to \infty$.

These imply that the image of $[0, \infty)^n$ under $P$ has the form $[0, M]$ for some $M \ge 0$.

Also,

5. $P(-x_1, \dotsc, -x_n) = -P(x_1, \dotsc, x_n)$ for any $x_1, \dotsc, x_n \in \mathbb R$.
6. $P(-\lvert x_1 \rvert, \dotsc, -\lvert x_n \rvert) \le P(x_1, \dotsc, x_n) \le P(\lvert x_1 \rvert, \dotsc, \lvert x_n \rvert)$ for any $x_1, \dotsc, x_n \in \mathbb R$.

These imply that the image of $(-\infty, 0]^n$ under $P$ is $[-M, 0]$ and that the image of the whole $\mathbb R^n$ under $P$ is thus $[-M, M]$.

Now, suppose $x_1, \dotsc, x_n \ge 0$ and $P(x_1, \dotsc, x_n) = M$. Since $M$ is a maximum for $P$, we have that
\begin{align*}
\frac \partial {\partial x_i} P & = \frac {1 \cdot \prod_j (x_j^2 + 1) - (\sum_j x_j) \cdot 2 x_i \prod_{j \neq i} (x_j^2 + 1)} {\prod_j (x_j^2 + 1)^2} \\
& = \frac {x_i^2 + 1 - 2(\sum_j x_j) x_i} {(x_i^2 + 1) \prod_j (x_j^2 + 1)} = 0
\end{align*}
Therefore, if we let $s = \sum_j x_j$, then all the $x_i$'s satisfy the same equation
$$x^2 - 2 s x+ 1 = 0$$
Since the equation has at least one solution, its discriminant must be nonnegative, i.e., $s^2 \ge 1$. Since we are assuming $x_1, \dotsc, x_n \ge 0$, we have $s \ge 0$, therefore $s \ge 1$.

Now, the solutions to the equation are $s + \sqrt{s^2 - 1}$ and $s - \sqrt{s^2 - 1}$. If $s = 1$, then they are both equal to $1$, and so all the $x_i$'s must be equal to $1$ (this can only happen if $n = 1$). If $s > 1$, then $\sqrt{s^2 - 1} > 0$ and $x_i$ can't be equal to the solution $s + \sqrt{s^2 - 1}$, because $x_i \le s < s + \sqrt{s^2 - 1}$. Therefore all the $x_i$'s must be equal to $s - \sqrt{s^2 - 1}$.

Since all the $x_i$'s are equal to the same $x$, we have that $s = n x$, and so $x$ satisfies the equation
$$x^2 - 2n x^2 + 1 = 0$$
that is,
$$x = \frac 1 {\sqrt {2n - 1}}$$

From this we can compute the maximum of $P$:
$$\sum_i x_i = \frac n {\sqrt {2n - 1}}$$
$$\prod_i (x_i^2 + 1) = \left (\frac 1 {2n - 1} + 1 \right )^n = \left ( \frac {2n} {2n - 1} \right )^n$$
and finally, the maximum is
$$M = \frac {\frac n {\sqrt {2n - 1}}} {\left ( \frac {2n} {2n - 1} \right )^n} = \frac { (2n - 1)^n } {2^n n^{n-1} \sqrt {2n - 1}}$$

The range of $P$ is then $[-M, M]$.

Comment: Since $x^2 - 2sx + 1 = 0$ is a quadratic equation which has two distinct solutions if $s^2 \neq 1$, there are actually two possible choices for each of $x_i$'s. So the question of whether all $x_i$'s have the same value needs further justification.

Comment: The solutions of $x^2 - 2sx + 1 = 0$ are $s \pm \sqrt{s^2 - 1}$. If they are distinct, then $s > 1$. But then $s + \sqrt{s^2 - 1} > s \ge x$, therefore $x \neq s + \sqrt{s^2 - 1}$. The only acceptable solution is thus $x = s - \sqrt{s^2 - 1}$.

Comment: Thank you for updating your argument. :)

Comment: @Luca Bressan Why it does give a maximal value? By the way, I have a proof that for $n=3$ and $n=4$ it indeed gives a maximal value. Why it works in the general?

Comment: @Luca Bressan What happens if $0<s<1.$ The is also, very interesting case $s=1$.

Comment: @Michael Rozenberg I've updated my answer to address your questions.

Comment: @Luca Bressan Why the equation has real root? Maybe the maximum occurs just when $0<s<1$. We need to consider this case and to prove that in this case we'll obtain a less value.

Comment: @Michael Rozenberg Suppose $(x_1, \dotsc, x_n)$ is such that $0 < s < 1$ and $P(x_1, \dotsc, x_n)$ is the maximum. Then $x_i < 1$ for any $i$ and so
$$\frac \partial {\partial x_i} P = \frac {x_i^2 + 1 - 2s x_i} {\dotsc} > \frac {x_i^2 + 1 - 2 x_i} {\dotsc} = \frac {(x_i - 1)^2} {\dotsc} > 0$$
which is a contradiction.

Comment: @Michael Rozenberg The assumption that $(x_1, \dotsc, x_n)$ is such that $P(x_1, \dotsc, x_n)$ is the maximum implies on its own that the equation $x^2 - 2sx + 1 = 0$ is satisfied by all the $x_i$'s, and so the equation must have at least one real root.

Comment: @Luca Bressan The case with $\frac{\partial P}{\partial x_i}>0$ is possible. It says that we have no a critical points inside the domain id est,  on the boundary of the domain.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/97818/discussion-between-luca-bressan-and-michael-rozenberg).