# Odd function and extremely values.

Tags: calculus, functions, inequality

I have a question in my mind as follow : Le $f:X\to Y$ be a odd function, continuous. If $f(a)=A, \quad a\in X$ is maximum/minimum, then $\implies f(-a)=-A, \quad -a\in X$ is minimum(maximum) ? Is that right or wrong? 
I think It is right but dunno how to prove it.

Here is an example: [Find the range of $P= \frac{\sum_{1}^n x_i}{\prod _{1}^n (x_i^2+1)}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3332716/find-the-range-of-p-frac-sum-1n-x-i-prod-1n-x-i21)

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that $a$ is a maximum point for $f$. Then $-a$ is a minimum point for $f$.

By contraddiction if there exists $b\neq -a$ such that

$f(x)<f(-a)$

Then

$f(-x)=-f(x)>-f(-a)=f(a)$

So $a$ is not a maximum point for $f$ and it is not possible.

You can observe that you don’t need to use the continuity of the function.

Answer (score 0):

I think we have: $x \in X \iff -x \in X$.

If this is the case and if $a \in X$ such that $f(x) \le f(a)$ for all $x \in X$, then

$$-f(a) \le -f(x)$$

for all $x \in A.$ Hence

$$f(-a) \le f(-x)$$

for all $x \in A.$

This gives $f(-a) \le f(z)$ for all $z \in A.$

Answer (score 0):

If $f(x)$ makes a minimum, $-f(x)$ makes a maximum, and conversely (because $f(x)\ge f(y)\iff -f(x)\le-f(y)$(.